# Firestore get a range of documents by row number

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this very big collection on a firestore, and I would like to be able to get a range of documents after sorting by a parameter, for example :

```
1 doc1
2 doc2
3 doc3
4 doc4
5 doc5
...
```

I would like to make a service function like `getRangeOfDocuments(start: number, end: number)` that would be called `getRangeOfDocuments(2, 4)` to get the documents `[doc2, doc3, doc4]`.

The `startAt` and `endAt` operators are taking documents as parameter, it means that to get the previous result I should have the `doc2` and `doc4` : `ref.startAt(doc2).endAt(doc4)`.

The `limit` operator can make it work for the case I want to get the range starting at `doc1`.

How can I get ranges not starting at `doc1` using row numbers instead of documents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have the ability to offset a query by some index in the result set.  You need to provide a document or value to continue the query from some point in the result set [as described in the documentation for pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).  (Think about how the indexes of the results may change over time as new data may have affected the outcome of the query, and you'll see that numeric indexing into results can generate bad results.)

Comment: It took me time to understand that I was thinking my problem upside down. Thank's for your help :).